# Definition of dual connection

Tags: differential-geometry

How to solve the following:

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle with connection $\nabla$ and $\pi:E^*\rightarrow M$ dual bundle (such that ${\pi^*}^{-1}(p)$ is a dual of $\pi^{-1}(p)$). How to show that 
$(\nabla^*_X \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma_2)=X_p(\sigma^*_1(\sigma_2))-\sigma_{2p}(\nabla_{X}\sigma_1)$ correctly defines connection of dual bundle?

Linear connection, by definition, is map $\nabla:\chi (M)\times\chi(M)\rightarrow \chi(M)$ with properties
$$\nabla_Y(X_1+X_2)=\nabla_Y(X_1)+\nabla_Y(X_2),$$
$$\nabla_{(Y_1+Y_2)}(X)=\nabla_{Y_1}(X)+\nabla_{Y_2}(X_2),$$
$$\nabla_{Y}f(X)=Y(f)X+f\nabla_{Y}X,$$
$$\nabla_{fY}X=f\nabla_{Y}X.$$
So, is the following ok:
$$(\nabla^*_X \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma_2^1+\sigma_2^2)=X_p(\sigma^*_1(\sigma_2^1+\sigma_2^2))-(\sigma_2^1+\sigma_2^2)_p(\nabla_{X}\sigma_1)=\dots=(\nabla^*_X \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma_2^1)+(\nabla^*_X \sigma_1^*)(\sigma_2^2),$$
$(\nabla^*_{X_1+X_2} \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma)=(X_1+X_2)_p(\sigma_1^*(\sigma_2))-\sigma_{2p}(\nabla_{X_1+X_2}\sigma_1)=\dots=(\nabla^*_{X_1} \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma_2)+(\nabla^*_{X_2} \sigma_1^*)_p(\sigma_2)?$

Also, how to check the other two conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The proof will depend on your definition of a connection, which you should include in your question.

Comment: Hint : to prove the remaining identities, it is enough to prove them _at every point in $M$._ To do that, just evaluate both sides of the identities in question on vectors $e\in E_m$, $m\in M$.

Comment: Could you please, show how to prove third condition (with vector e,  as you suggested)? Thanks in advance.